# How much power is needed to drive two times faster?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, drag, power

Suppose a cyclist riding at speed $v$ decides to accelerate to speed $2v$. Does she have to generate $8$ times more power to sustain that speed?

$P_1=F_dv$

If we double the speed, (it usually happens that the air drag increases quadratically) then the drag force $F_d$ will increase to $4F_d$.

$P_2=4F_d2v=8P_1$

Answer (score 2):

As with most questions in fluid dynamics, physics goes up against rather more approximations than usual when discussing things like fluid friction!

As an overall first-order estimate, indeed you are correct. The often-used drag equation gives the force experienced when moving through a fluid:
$$
F = \frac{1}{2} \rho v^2 C_D A
$$
where $\rho$, $A$, and $C_D$ should remain relatively constant in this situation (they are the air density, cross-sectional area of the cyclist, and the drag coefficient, respectively), and so the force will increase with the square of the velocity.

Power is then given as you stated, and so the final power value will have a cubic dependency on velocity: doubling it will force the power to increase by a factor of 8 to maintain constant velocity.

This is, of course, not taking into account the friction with the ground and the dissipative mechanisms within the bike itself, but assuming the difference in their effects is negligible between $v$ and $2v$, the approximation holds.